# change XSD definition value of minoccurs maxoccurs

Tags: geoserver, openjump

How can I change the XSD definition  values of the 'Feature Type Details'' attributes `minOccurs`and `maxOccurs`of a Layer, either in Geoserver or in OpenJump?

(as in `<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MyElement" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>`)

Comment: what is your underlying datastore? in general it doesn't make sense to change these

Comment: my datastore is a dbf file. I just want to change it to give a try to the solution in the last comment here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129906/string-update-only-first-character-gets-stored