# Update WFS Layer with QGIS - Commit errors

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

In QGis: Importing WFS Layer from Server, changing Attributes, trying to save.

I get `Commit errors: Could not commit changes to layer ah_neu:mylayer`.

The geoservers logfile says:

> 2015-01-21 11:40:05,229 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler
> mapping found for [/ah_neu/ows] 2015-01-21 11:40:05,229 TRACE
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/ah_neu/ows]
> 2015-01-21 11:40:05,229 DEBUG [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapping
> [/ah_neu/ows] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler
> [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@6b8246a7] and 1 interceptor 2015-01-21
> 11:40:05,292 DEBUG [geoserver.requests] - First 4 bytes of XML doc are
> : 3C ('<') 54 ('T') 72 ('r') 61 ('a') 2015-01-21 11:40:05,292 DEBUG
> [geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 1. Inferred encoding:
> UTF-8 2015-01-21 11:40:05,292 DEBUG [geoserver.requests] - Invalid(?)
> XML declaration: <Trans. 2015-01-21 11:40:05,292 DEBUG
> [geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 2. Charset in XML
> declaration is `null`. 2015-01-21 11:40:05,292 DEBUG
> [geoserver.requests] - Trying to create reader basing on existing
> charset information: `UTF-8`. 2015-01-21 11:40:05,292 DEBUG
> [geoserver.ows] - Raw XML request: GRABNAMEABC�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
> 2015-01-21 11:40:05,293 INFO [geoserver.wfs] -  Request:
> getServiceInfo 2015-01-21 11:40:05,296 DEBUG [geotools.xml] -
> schemaLocation found: myserver.de/ah_neu
> http://myserver.de/geoserver/ah_neu/ows?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAME=ah_neu:Graeber&SRSNAME=EPSG:31466
> 2015-01-21 11:40:32,611 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler
> mapping found for [/web/] 2015-01-21 11:40:32,611 TRACE
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
> 2015-01-21 11:40:32,611 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler
> mapping found for [/web/] 2015-01-21 11:40:32,611 TRACE
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
> 2015-01-21 11:40:32,613 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 1513 locking in
> mode WRITE 2015-01-21 11:40:32,613 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 1513
> got the lock in mode WRITE 2015-01-21 11:40:32,615 DEBUG
> [org.geoserver] - Thread 1513 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
> 2015-01-21 11:40:32,615 DEBUG
> [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] -
> SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
> 2015-01-21 11:40:32,699 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler
> mapping found for [/web/] 2015-01-21 11:40:32,699 TRACE
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
> 2015-01-21 11:40:32,699 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler
> mapping found for [/web/] 2015-01-21 11:40:32,699 TRACE
> [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
> 2015-01-21 11:40:32,699 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 1513 locking in
> mode WRITE 2015-01-21 11:40:32,699 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 1513
> got the lock in mode WRITE 2015-01-21 11:40:32,703 DEBUG
> [geoserver.web] - cannot convert url:
> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.4.4.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/screen.css
> to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for
> polling 2015-01-21 11:40:32,705 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert
> url:
> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.4.4.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/print.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for
> polling 2015-01-21 11:40:32,706 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert
> url:
> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.4.4.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/geoserver.css
> to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for
> polling 2015-01-21 11:40:32,707 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert
> url:
> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.4.4.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/ie.css
> to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for
> polling 2015-01-21 11:40:32,708 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert
> url:
> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.4.4.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js
> to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for
> polling 2015-01-21 11:40:32,709 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert
> url:
> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.4.4.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery.inline-info.js
> to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for
> polling

How can I store the changes without error?

Comment: Probably related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115471/qgis-wfs-error-could-not-commit-changes-to-layer